# Change Linux Bcache device type

Tags: opensuse, cache, ssd, bcache, ssd-hdd-hybrid

I have accidentally configured my SSD as a backing device instead of a caching device. Simply trying either one of the following:

```
sudo make-bcache -C /dev/sdb1
sudo make-bcache -C /dev/sdb
```

Gives the errors:

```
Can't open dev /dev/sdb1: Device or resource busy
Can't open dev /dev/sdb: Device or resource busy
```

How does one rectify a situation like this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the kernel to close the bcache device before rerunning `make-bcache` on the underlying device.

To close a backing device:

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/<device>/bcache/stop
```

To close a cache device:

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/<device>/bcache/set/unregister
```

(See the [documentation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/master/Documentation/bcache.txt) for more details.)

So in your case, if you accidentally configured the `/dev/sdb1` partition as a backing device, you can close it with

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdb/sdb1/bcache/stop
```

and then rerun `make-bcache` with the `--wipe-bcache` option to overwrite the previous setup:

```
make-bcache --wipe-bcache -C /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: You can add the `-B`acking devs simultaneously. It saves a step later. You don't have to do all of that registering. And anyway - haven't the `bcache-tools` provided more direct options for this stuff yet?